# Any traditional sources that compare Rachav to the wife who hid Dovid in Shmuel II, perek 17?

Tags: king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of, joshua--book-of

Rachav hides the spies under some flax, then tells enemy they went in a different direction.

The wife of the man in Bochurim hides Ahimaaz and Yehonasan under groats/ground wheat, and tells the enemy they went across a body of water.

Seems like there's some parallels to me. Any comparisons?